# How to write XML content from xml.etree.ElementTree to a file?

Tags: xml, python-3.x

I’m using python 3.5

In order to extract the text contents from a word document, I have used xml.etree.ElementTree.
I can’t able to write the resulting XML content into other file.

Below is my piece of code

```
import zipfile
import xml.etree.ElementTree
with zipfile.ZipFile('<path to docx file>') as docx:
    tree = xml.etree.ElementTree.XML(docx.read('word/document.xml'))
```

I have tried two methods:
`tree.write('<path to file>', encoding='utf8')` 
and

```
xml.etree.ElementTree.write('<path to file>')
```

But both of the methods throws the error as:

AttributeError: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'write'

​Kindly help.​

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*tree* is generaly an ElementTree object, while *root* is its child root Element.

Loading with `xml.etree.ElementTree.parse()` returns a proper ElementTree.

```
# XML() -> returns root Element
root = xml.etree.ElementTree.XML(docx.read('word/document.xml'))
print(root)
<Element '{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}document' at 0x7f5f117ae5d0>


# parse() -> returns tree ElementTree
tree = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse(docx.open('word/document.xml'))
print(tree)
<xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree object at 0x7f5f11805890>

root = tree.getroot()
print(root)
<Element '{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}document' at 0x7f5f11805950>
```

Then :

```
import zipfile
import xml.etree.ElementTree

with zipfile.ZipFile('<path to docx file>') as docx:
    tree = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse(docx.open('word/document.xml'))

tree.write('<path to file>')
```